# Global convergence versus convergence to a global

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, definition

I have been reading many optimization papers and wanted to know what the difference between global convergence and convergence to a global is.  Sounds like the same thing to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Global convergence means that you will converge to a local optimum no matter what starting point you consider.

Convergence to a global means you converge to a global optimum (much harder).